# GCKDeviceManager Class : joinApplication:sessionID

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to understand the purpose of this function.
With this function I can connect two applications? I mean two different senders/iOS app to one receiver?

An example would be great, thanks.

I am using this example: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement Leon's comment, in **most case**, your sender can simply use `launchApplication`; this method takes a parameter that determines whether to reuse a running session or re-launch even if a session is currently going on for the same application. In a typical use case, a sender at start up just uses this method and sets the parameter to not start a new session if one is already running. In other words, it starts the application if it is not already running or joins if it is already running. `joinApplication` is **mostly** used when you want to reconnect yourself after an implicit  disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Cast receivers can have multiple senders connected at a time. Typically you use joinApplication to join a receiver application already running on the Cast device. If you have persisted the sessionId, then this will attempt to rejoin that session. If the session is no longer the same or another app is running, then this will fail.

Comment: Thank you, to this I can connect the app/sender 1, watch a movie and if I want to start the app/sender 2 to watch another movie on the same TV I can use this class to compare between those applications sessions and disallow the application 2 to kick the app 1 without warning? I am simulating in two different machines and the session is the same on both.

Comment: If Sender A connects to your receiver and creates session S, then as long as the receive application is not shut down it will maintain that session S, no matter how any senders come and go. So you cannot stop sender B from starting a new movie based on the session information. You also mentioned App 1 and App 2, I presume you didn't really mean different apps but rather the same app but different senders. As a side note, one application cannot stop a second application from launching.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanations very useful.